# Return the elements of a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to return the content from the row () if I click on any of the  of .

```
<table id="dataTable" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Empresa</th>
            <th>Criado</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="id-cliente-14">14</td>
            <td>Name here</td>
            <td>contato@test.com</td>
            <td>sdfsf</td>
            <td>2017-03-13 11:31:58</td>
            <td>
                <a href="" class="actions_icons pencil"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>                             
                <a href="" class="actions_icons trash"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

With this code:

```
    $("i.fa.fa-pencil").on( "click", function() {
        console.log( $(this).parent().parent().parent().text() );
    });
```

I get this result on the console:

```
14Name herecontato@test.comsdfsf2017-03-13 11:31:58
```

I can't work with this, I need to get the ID alone, and if this is not hard get all the others  alone too.

I can put css class or and id in the  or another tag if this could make it more easy.

Comment: Have you tried `("#id-cliente-14").text()`?

Comment: Yep, that's works, but how to get this if the id is dynamically generated? it's a <php? echo "id-cliente-".$id; ?>

Comment: I think you could also echo the data in js, like this : `("<?php echo 'id-cliente-'.$id; ?>").text()`

Comment: My js script are in another file separated from the php code.

Comment: Then create a static `id`, like `cliente-id` or something

Comment: It's not wrong to have the same id in a HTML?

Comment: I think you have an answer now

Comment: ids cannot be duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently selecting `<tbody>` as it is the parent's parent's parent. If you want the first `<td>` you could select the parent's first sibling or the grandparent's first child, such as:

```
$("i.fa.fa-pencil").on( "click", function() {
    console.log( $(this).closest("tr").children(":first").text() );
});
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, I tryed to use children and closest, but I used wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Did you Try SomeThing like that?

```
$("#id-cliente-14").on( "click", function() {
    console.log( "ID: "+ $(this).parents('tr').find('td')[0].innerText);
    console.log( "NAM: "+ $(this).parents('tr').find('td')[1].innerText);
});
```

--EDIT

I got it

I think its works:

```
$(".pencil").on( "click", function(e) {
    console.log( "ID: "+ $(this).parents('tr').find('td')[0].innerText);
    console.log( "NAM: "+ $(this).parents('tr').find('td')[1].innerText);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I think that would take the value of all `td` under the `tr`, same as OP's

Comment: This works, but I have to click on the #id-cliente-14, not in the <a> or <i>

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("i.fa.fa-pencil").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Id of first td "+$(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").attr("id"));
  console.log("Text of first td "+$(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(1)").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Empresa</th>
      <th>Criado</th>
      <th>Ações</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="id-cliente-14">14</td>
      <td>Name here</td>
      <td>contato@test.com</td>
      <td>sdfsf</td>
      <td>2017-03-13 11:31:58</td>
      <td>
        <a href="" class="actions_icons pencil"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true">pencil</i></a>
        <a href="" class="actions_icons trash"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true">trash</i></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Use `.closest()`

Comment: Tryed your js code, it's give me a error, but I think this could work if the errors are corrected, maybe are some typo. Thanks!